# Bind NSTableColumn to NSArrayController programmatically

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, nstableview

How can i bind a NSTableViewColumn to an NSArrayController programmatically?
i have a table with 2 columns that are already bound to the array controller. but i am adding new columns at Runtime, and these need to be bound to the arrangedObjects of the arraycontroller. its a cellbased NSTableview. I only found this code online but am not able to make it work..

```
 NSString *akey = @"somekey";
 NSString *keypath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"arrangedObjects.%@",akey];
 [newColumn bind:@"value" toObject:arrayController withKeyPath:keypath options:nil];
```

i am not sure about the "bind:" part and did not understand the apple documentation, that says that i have to expose a binding..

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Comment: What doesn't work? Is the column missing entirely? Does the column exist but data is not populate?

Comment: It gives me an error and does not execute the rest of the code in that method. If i include the code above my columns are not added programmatically anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace "value" with NSValueBinding
should work